# "Required" attribute not working when "AllowHtml" attribute is used. MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to post a html with a wysiwyg editor so I used `[AllowHtml]` attribute on my property. It works, but when I use it with `[Required]` and `[StringLength]` attributes, it stops working. `ModelState.IsValid` returns true even if prop is empty.

Yes, I know I can manually control it if it is null and add an error to `ModelState`, but why?

Why this happens? Is there a better way to post some HTML code to back-end?

My dto:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = CErr.RequiredField)]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = CErr.Min5Max100)]
[MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = CErr.Min5Max100)]
public string Name { get; set; }

[AllowHtml]
[Required(ErrorMessage = CErr.RequiredField)]
[StringLength(4000, ErrorMessage = CErr.TooLongValue)]
public string HtmlBody { get; set; }
```

My action:

```
[Route("new")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewMessageLayout(ManageMessageLayoutDto model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var response = Repositories.MessageLayoutRepository.SaveMessageLayout(model, CurrentUser.Id);

        if (response.Status == ResultStatus.Success)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("MessageManagement");
        }

        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("error", response.Message);
            return View("ManageMessageLayout", model);
        }
    }

    return View("ManageMessageLayout", model);
}
```

And some HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

    <label>Name <span class="req">*</span></label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "label label-danger" })

    <label>Content <span class="req">*</span></label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HtmlBody)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HtmlBody, null, new { @class = "label label-danger" })

    <input class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg" type="submit" value="@(editing ? "Save" : "Add")" />
}
```

Comment: Are you using any rich text editor like tiny mce or Ckeditor?

Comment: @MDDDC Yea I am using Ckeditor but I tried it with a regular textbox and area but it's same...

Comment: Are you getting any data on post method for HTmlBody?can you put an brake point and take a look?

Comment: @MDDDC It seems null my friend.

Comment: can you please show your html ?

Comment: Have you tried decorating your action with `[ValidateInput(false)]`?

Comment: Also try to add MinLength to your stringlength atribute , set MinLength=1

Comment: @gkon , are you sure that if you will take off [AllowHtml] attribute validation will work as expected?

Comment: What if you just drop the [AllowHtml] attribute? You don't need this in order for it to work.

Comment: @haim770 I can't use it because it will skip all of my validations on that action and I don't want this.

Comment: @MDDDC yes it works if I remove [AllowHtml]

Comment: @gkon, just do a test without alloHtml attribute to see if validation will work , try to not input anything, your problem might be in something else.

Comment: @stibay then I will get an error saying "a potentially dangerous request form value was detected from the client"

Comment: @gkon, can you please try to remove String Length attribute at all and do one more test,I suppose currently default MinLength=0, this way Required attribute is omitted...

Comment: @MDDDC It's same. I tried it in every ways. It all happens when AllowHtml joins to them. I know, it is weird...

Comment: @gkon ok, let me try on my side then.

Comment: @gkon I just added your code to an empty mvc project , and it's working as expected.

Comment: @gkon, "It seems null my friend." What do you mean by that? It's either null or not. Did you put a breakpoint?

Comment: @MDDDC IT is so weird. I think this happening since I upgraded to Visual Studio 2015. I'll investigate this.

Comment: @ataravati Sorry for my expression. It is null.

Comment: @gkon, is this in an Edit action or Add?

Comment: @gkon I just added your code to an empty mvc project , and it's working as expected.Try to text on more time with exactly the code that you have posted.

Comment: @ataravati I am using this action for both of edit and add.

Comment: And, you have the same problem in both cases?

Comment: @ataravati yes. Now I posted all my action and dto.

Comment: What about your GET action? Did you check if the `HtmlBody` property is null before being sent to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

My presentation layer was using 5.2.2.0 version of `System.Web.Mvc` but repository layer was using 5.2.3.0. I downgraded this to 5.2.2.0. And now it is working normally.

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to replicate your error.  However, I did notice a few things.  First, according to the ckEditor documentation, `textbox` is not a valid attaching point for the editor.  You should use `textarea`.

[CkEditor Developer Documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter)

> At this point any textarea, p, or div element can be transformed into
>   a rich text editor by using the ckeditor() method.

Next, notice that I added `AllowEmptyStrings=false` to the `[Required(` attribute.  This may be the important piece you are missing (will test without) - **Testing seems to indicate that not setting AllowEmptyStrings does not impact the results of this test setup as the [default value for this property is false](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The model was still invalid.**

**Setup**

1. VS 2015, MVC 5.2.2, .NET 4.5.1, jQuery 1.10.2, ckEditor 3.6.4

**View Model**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This should be filled out")]
    [StringLength(4000, ErrorMessage="Its too big")]
    public string HtmlBody { get; set; } 
}
```

**Controller Actions**

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View(new TestViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(TestViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) throw new Exception();
        var test = model.HtmlBody;
        return RedirectToAction("Contact");
    }
```

**View**

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.TestViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>Test of HTML</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label>Content <span class="req">*</span></label>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.HtmlBody)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HtmlBody, null, new { @class = "label label-danger" })
    <input type ="submit" value="test on server"/>
}

@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#HtmlBody').ckeditor();
    });
</script>
}
```

**Results:**
 *Basically, the exception was thrown because the model state was invalid*
[image]

Comment: Thanks Tommy. I'll try AllowEmptyStrings. And, I know textbox is not for ckeditor but I was using  before this and I changed it to textbox just for test.

Comment: @gkon - my test showed that it did not make a difference, it should be default false.

Comment: 'AllowEmptyStrings' doesn't work too. I created another project too and got error like you. I tried without attribute routing, every combination of validation attributes and many different post data but it's same. 'AllowHtml' prevents all other attributes from work.

Comment: @gkon - it only prevents it from working in your one project.  There is something else going on with that control / property.  Ensure that ckEditor isn't sending over an empty tag `<p/>` for example.  That's about anyone here can help you with until we can deduce what is different from your configuration vs out of the box implementation.